# How to effectively decompose a dictionary containing nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has thousands of keys and each key has a corresponding nested dictionaries. As a MWE, I'm showing a very simple structure.

```
original_dict = {
    'H0JKYXRWSN0D': {'type': 'A', 'name': '5GJ3VT3P'},
    'T3W8Z1G3ZJFS': {'type': 'B', 'name': '2QNVJGM6'},
    'ZJ7VYG1J33FJ': {'type': 'B', 'name': 'UJV0LEH2'},
    'DK0MBF8N4H1S': {'type': 'A', 'name': '8X0JBY1R'},
    'DZC6UHTQ93UO': {'type': 'C', 'name': '83B4FLJ3'}
}
```

My goal is to create individual lists for each unique type in the dictionary as:

```
{'A': ['H0JKYXRWSN0D', 'DK0MBF8N4H1S'], 'B': ['T3W8Z1G3ZJFS', 'ZJ7VYG1J33FJ'], 'C': ['DZC6UHTQ93UO']}
```

For instance, I would like to see all the keys that has type A. I can do this in a for loop, but was curious if there is a more efficient way to do like a built-in function that is faster than using a simple for loop. Here's my current solution.

```
def create_lists_by_type(dictionary):
    lists_by_type = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if value['type'] not in lists_by_type:
            lists_by_type[value['type']] = []
        lists_by_type[value['type']].append(key)
    return lists_by_type
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than the for loop. You can get rid of the `if` statement by using `defaultdict()` or `dict.setdefault()`. But the basic structure remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `defaultdict` just to reduce the work of checking the key and then creating value field and adding value, by directly appending value to keys.

Below is code, little clean.

```
>>> original_dict = {
...     'H0JKYXRWSN0D': {'type': 'A', 'name': '5GJ3VT3P'},
...     'T3W8Z1G3ZJFS': {'type': 'B', 'name': '2QNVJGM6'},
...     'ZJ7VYG1J33FJ': {'type': 'B', 'name': 'UJV0LEH2'},
...     'DK0MBF8N4H1S': {'type': 'A', 'name': '8X0JBY1R'},
...     'DZC6UHTQ93UO': {'type': 'C', 'name': '83B4FLJ3'}
... }
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for k, v in original_dict.items():
...     result[v['type']].append(k)
... 
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['H0JKYXRWSN0D', 'DK0MBF8N4H1S'], 'B': ['T3W8Z1G3ZJFS', 'ZJ7VYG1J33FJ'], 'C': ['DZC6UHTQ93UO']})
>>> 
>>> dict(result)
{'A': ['H0JKYXRWSN0D', 'DK0MBF8N4H1S'], 'B': ['T3W8Z1G3ZJFS', 'ZJ7VYG1J33FJ'], 'C': ['DZC6UHTQ93UO']}
>>>
```

so you can use this  function

```
from collections import defaultdict


def create_lists_by_type(dictionary):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        result[v['type']].append(k)
    return dict(result)
```